# Facebook SDK unity: 'UnityEditor.PlayerSettings.get_applicationIdentifier'?

Tags: facebook, sdk, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I have installed Facebook unity SDK 7.10.1 and start getting this error:

```
"MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'UnityEditor.PlayerSettings.get_applicationIdentifier'.
Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor (RuntimeTypeHandle type) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.CompilerServices/RuntimeHelpers.cs:101)
UnityEditor.EditorAssemblies.ProcessEditorInitializeOnLoad (System.Type type) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/EditorAssemblies.cs:130)"
```

I have uninstalled the SDK 7.10.1 and installed SDK 7.9.4 and still getting this error. I am using Unity 5.5.3p4 (64 bit).